# React how to remove deadcode in react?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, code-cleanup

Imagine we have a project1 with a binary tree component structure. And project2 is a repo of it. Now suppose in level 3, say component A,B,C,D.. D is deleted. Is there a way to delete all components below D which are not used by other components ? Also is there a way to delete actions which are not used anymore ?

Comment: Sure: Delete files one at a time, until your program breaks. If the program breaks, that file was needed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean, but you might want to look into [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

Comment: actually you can use webstorm or an smart IDE in order to remove useless actions